# Removal of a cloned div (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an already existing div when hovering above an element.
The element has an id that matches the div.

The cloning and displaying part works on hover but I stuck removing the already cloned element. I saw closet mentioned in another answer but I probably use it wrong.

```js
$('.referer').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    $('#reply_' + id).clone().appendTo(this);
}, function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    $('#reply_' + id).closest(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reply_1">
First Post
</div>
<div id="reply_2">
Second Post
</div>
<div id="reply_3">
Third Post
</div>
<!--The id is the id of the quoted post-->
<p>
<span class="referer" id="1">Quoted Link (First Post)</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `closest()` function in this case but `find()` instead, like :

```
$(this).find('#reply_' + id).remove();
```

So simply you looks for `'#reply_' + id` inside the current element `this` and remove it.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.referer').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    $('#reply_' + id).clone().appendTo(this);
}, function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    $(this).find('#reply_' + id).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reply_1">First Post</div>
<div id="reply_2">Second Post</div>
<div id="reply_3">Third Post</div>
<!--The id is the id of the quoted post-->
<p>
<span class="referer" id="1">Quoted Link (First Post)</span>
<br>
<span class="referer" id="2">Quoted Link (Second Post)</span>
<br>
<span class="referer" id="3">Quoted Link (Third Post)</span>
```